# text in HTML becomes split / malformed in the DOM when elements are inserted around text and then removed (preserving the inner text, though)

Tags: javascript, html, string, dom

So, here is normal text: just your standard paragraph.

[image: Normal Text]

I have javascript that will insert a span around selected text (for highlighting purposes).
The problem is that when I remove the span, the nice text block becomes chunky, and malformed:

[image]

How do I restore the block of text to its original state?

Comment: What is your JavaScript?

Comment: javascript is technically here: http://jsfiddle.net/DerNalia/rCVLf/3/ but I haven't been able to get the library to play nice with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must to keep the original node, and replace it cloning the innerHTML with your span-wraper. Then just replace the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the span, try replacing the content of the standard paragraph with its original data.